# Generate pseudorandom well conditioned equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to test my GMRES_C(k) implementation, however for random matrices the convergence is very bad (does not converge with restarts).

Is there any special (complex) matrix which is "pseudorandom" and well conditioned?

I have already thought about Gram-Schmidt and searched for recent publications, however it was not really useful.

Comment: The condition number of random matrices (uniform, normal distribution) is not a problem; these matrices have small condition numbers. The problem is the distribution of the eigenvalues which makes GMRES to converge slowly. So you better generate matrices with some "nice" clustered spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

A general trick for constructing a matrix by their conditioning is as following. This is Matlab code. You can construct an arbitrarily conditioned matrix by generating the singular values and constructing the diagonal.

```
function A = randommatrix(m,n,kappa)
% Returns an m x n matrix with condition number kappa,
% exponentially graded singular values
k = min(m,n);
[Q1,R1] = qr(randn(m,m));
[Q2,R2] = qr(randn(n,n));
% Originally thought we would evaluate for any m x n matrix, so if not square took minimum dimension
U = Q1(1:m,1:k);
V = Q2(1:k,1:n);
j=k-1;
% Take k-1 root of condition number to get number for grade
l = kappa^(1/j);
% Construct the singular value matrix, l^0 = 1, then l^(k-1)= 1/kappa 
S = diag(l.^(0:-1:-j));

A = U*S*V;


end
```

I'm not sure if this is right here. Now just multiply through afterward.

```
m=10;
n=m;
kappa=1;

A = randommatrix(m,n,kappa)

B = A*i;
```